# How will i get the span class id under which the text belongs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML** (contenteditable div)

```
<div id="board">
   <div>int main<span class="openParen bm1">(</span><span class="closeParen bm1">)</span>{</div>
   <div>if<span class="openParen bm2">(</span> <span class="openParen bm3">(</span>x>1<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span> && <span class="openParen bm4">(</span>x<10<span class="closeParen bm4">)</span> <span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></div>
   <div>statement;</div>
   <div>}</div>
</div>
```

I am using an xloop for the rows, and yloop for the characters inside each row.

1.) How would i able to get the `span class` of the 2nd `(` (xloop:1 yloop:7)  w/c is `bm2`?

2.) How would i get the `span`s BETWEEN `bm2`, i will loop in each of them and store the text of the span inside an array

**JS**

```
for( var x=0; x<$('#board > div ').size(); x++ ){
    var inlineDiv_num_text = $('#board > div ').eq(x).text();
    for( var y=0; y<$('#board > div ').eq(x).text().length; y++){

         kword_search = kword_search + inlineDiv_num_text.charAt(y);
         // i will detect the target paren here
          if(/(if|while|for)\s*\($/.test(kword_search)){
            //know w/c span the ( belongs to
            //get the bm span inside of it
         }
    }
}
```

GOAL: Store the `bm` groupings inside an array

```
 array[0] = ( (x>1) && (x<10) )
 array[1] = (x>1)
 array[2] = (x<10)
```

Comment: Is *w/c* an abbreviation for something? What?

Comment: @TRiG: I/s abbre/n f/r "which"

Comment: *I am using an xloop for the rows, and yloop for the characters inside each row.* - you're using what? How? Could you please *show* us how you're doing this?

Comment: @extraRice Unless the first two comments tipped you off: you shouldn't use abbreviations in SO posts. You have enough time to type out the words that can't be abbreviated and to detour from your work to prepare the question, you have enough time for those extra 3-4 characters.

Comment: And what's the `for for` meant to be doing, other than causing a syntax error? Also `&` should *not* be used in HTML, it should be encoded with `&amp;`, and `<` should be `&lt;` (I'm led to believe that `>` can appear as text (but I can't remember why I think that, so I'm unsure) though it always feels wrong).

Comment: @David Thomas, sorry i forgot to mention that it is a contenteditable div, code editor project

Comment: You're using `#board_code` when you only have `#board` in your HTML. Also, you're not declaring `kword_search` as an empty string, which causes an error when you try to append to it.

Comment: Actually there is no syntax error and it works fine including that kword_search im just having trouble posting it here, wherein there is no problem in that already, i just wanted to show the loop sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this answers your first and second questions.

It gives you the spans inside the "openParen" and "closeParen" of the "bm2" class, and stores the text inside an array. (This only captures the brackets, because only the brackets are inside the spans.)

```
var open = $('span[class="openParen bm2"]')
var spans = open.nextUntil('span[class="closeParen bm2"]')
var inside = []
$.each(spans, function(i, span){
    inside.push($(span).html())
})
alert(inside.join('-'))
```

Example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKxhR/3/)

**EDIT**

Not sure how you'll do "between the span tags", I'd start by getting the html of the parent div element, and passing the spans using regex:

```
var allcontent = $('span[class="openParen bm2"]').parent().html()
var betweenSpan = allcontent.split(/<span class="openParen bm2">[^<]*<\/span>|<span class="closeParen bm2">[^<]*<\/span>/)[1]
var valuesArray = betweenSpan.split(/<[^>]*>/)
```

Gives you the js array:

```
[" ", "(", "x&gt;1", ")", " &amp;&amp; ", "(", "x&lt;10", ")", " "]
```

Example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKxhR/4/)

Definitely not pretty.

**A better solution** would be to reconsider the structure of your html tags (i.e. put the values you want to capture inside some tags!)

Anyway, that's enough, I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: Updated, it should be between on number 2, sorry men

Comment: Ok, i thinks this is more simpler. how about wrapping ALL the bm match with into a new span. ... putting the values i want to capture inside some tags!

Comment: New approach, will this be applicable, thanks for your help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583687/wrapping-the-pair-of-span-having-similar-class-name