# How will i able to get the DOM position of the character

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="board">
  <div>ab X</div>
  <div>a <span class='target'>V</span> b</div>
  <div>Xab</div>
<div>
```

I wanted to access the DOM place of `V` in my HTML and alert `V`, I must not use `$('#board').eq(1).text().charAt(2)`. I need its DOM position so that I can easily trace the span that is wrapping the `V`.

THIS is not working, What's the right way?

```
alert($('#board').eq(1).eq(2).text());
```

This is the original problem, i can get someone who can help me so im trying to revised it [How will i get the span class id under which the text belongs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581703/how-will-i-get-the-span-class-id-under-w-c-the-text-belongs)

**ALGORTIHM:**

```
1. Found V from row looping and y looping 
2. Find the span where it belongs to
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$('span.target')`? Isn't that what that class is there for?

Comment: "I must not use $('#board').eq(1).text().charAt(2)." Why not?

Comment: @undefined: what if its not at the first?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, so I removed my comment.

Comment: Please clarify your goal here.

Comment: @thilo: its not how my algorithm goes, it first searches for V and then wrap it: i just chopped this as good as i can from my unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581703/how-will-i-get-the-span-class-id-under-w-c-the-text-belongs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `span` elements that have `V` text content should be selected, you can use `.filter()` method:

```
var $span = $('#board span').filter(function() {
   return (this.textContent || this.innerText) === 'V';
});
```

Getting index of selected element:

```
$span.index();
```

Index of the `V` character within the text content of span's parent element:

```
var vIndex = $span.parent().text().indexOf('V');
```

---

Note that jQuery returns a jQuery-wrapped array of the selected elements, as you are using ID selector, the returned collection has only one *wrapper/top-level* selected element:

```
Object[div#board]
```

`.eq(1)`(*just like getting an element by index from a simple array*) returns the second top-level selected element that doesn't exist in the collection. Apart from that chaining `.eq()` methods in that way doesn't make any sense as it returns only one element.

Comment: real helpful but i think i cant still apply based on the algorithm i stated. If you just want to, you can take a look the basis of this question why im sticking to that algorithm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581703/how-will-i-get-the-span-class-id-under-which-the-text-belongs