# Wrap pair of <span> having similar class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**CONTENTEDITABLE DIV** sample string only

```
int main(){

 if((x<3 && x!=5) || x>10)
   //execute statement;

 while((y<10) && (y>1))
   //execute statement;

}
```

**EXISTING HTML OF THE DIV**

```
<div id="board_code">
 <div>int main<span class="openParen bm1">(</span><span class="closeParen bm1">)</span></div>
 <div></div>
 <div>if<span class="openParen bm2">(</span><span class="openParen bm3">(</span>x<3 && x!=5<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span> || x>10<span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>while<span class="openParen bm4">(</span><span class="openParen bm5">(</span>y<10<span class="closeParen bm5">)</span> && <span class="openParen bm6">(</span>y>1<span class="closeParen bm6">)</span><span class="closeParen bm4">)</span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>}</div>
</div>
```

**TARGET HTML**

```
<div id="board_code">
 <div>int main<span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm1">(</span><span class="closeParen bm1">)</span></span></div>
 <div></div>
 <div>if<span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm2">(</span><span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm3">(</span>x<3 && x!=5<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span></span> || x>10<span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>while<span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm4">(</span><span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm5">(</span>y<10<span class="closeParen bm5">)</span></span> && <span class="parenWrap"><span class="openParen bm6">(</span>y>1<span class="closeParen bm6">)</span></span><span class="closeParen bm4">)</span></span></div>
 <div>//execute statement;</div>
 <div>}</div>
</div>
```

I've already matched the `()` by having a pair of `bm1, bm2`, etc.. Now, i need to wrap the `openParen bm(n)` to `closeParen bm(n)` with `span class = parenWrap`

How can i achieve this?

**SIMPLIFIED**

```
<span class="parenWrap">((x<3 && x!=5) || x>10)</span>
<span class="parenWrap">(x<3 && x!=5)</span>
<span class="parenWrap">((y<10) && (y>1))</span>
<span class="parenWrap">(y<10)</span>
<span class="parenWrap">(y>1)</span>
```

For easier understanding, they will become like this, retaining the span tags they already have

**UPDATE** based from @pdoherty926 answer

The logic is something like

```
//if i have 3 pairs of bm's
    for(var xx=1; xx<4; xx++){
         $('.openParen bm'+xx).nextUntil('.closeParen bm'+xx).andSelf().wrapAll('<span class="parenWrap"></span>');
    }//for
```

but this is not working.

Comment: `(x<3 && x!=5)` the *and* is quite useless here. If `x` is smaller than `3`, it's certainly not equal to `5`.

Comment: @plax: that's just a string, dont mind it

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>   
    one
    <span class="openParen bm1">(</span>
    <span>sometext here</span>
    <span class="closeParen bm1">)</span>
</div>


$('.openParen').each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.closeParen').andSelf().wrapAll('<span class="parenWrap"></span>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dGjT/7/)

Comment: When i try to put a text inside the (), it should also wrap the text inside ( ) http://jsfiddle.net/8dGjT/4/

Comment: See my updated answer. (The updated answer expects the inner text to be inside *some* element.)

Comment: Hmmm i think u need to use their same class like bm1 and bm2, this just wrap the nearest found ). So if i found one ( and found ( and found ), they will all be wrapped up